# HDMI to DVI-D SL/DVI-D DL adapters signal distortion

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, display-adapter

Have encountered the following problem:

**Asus ROG G501JW :**
HDMI <-> DVI-D DL adapter causes severe *color distortion* on external monitor with DVI-D DL port.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbLdE.jpg
HDMI <-> DVI-D SL adapter works perfectly.
HDMI port is wired to the internal graphics processor Intel HD 4600.

**PC :**
Both adapters operate just fine.
HDMI port is wired to a dedicated Nvidia card then.

```
HDMI port (Asus G501JW) 
HDMI <-> HDMI cable
HDMI <-> DVI-D SL/DL adapter
DVI-D DL port (NEC Multisync E224wi)
```

```
HDMI port (PC) 
HDMI <-> HDMI cable
HDMI <-> DVI-D SL/DL adapter
DVI-D DL port (NEC Multisync E224wi)
```

What's the root of the issue? Not enough power of integrated graphics processor in laptop?
Is there any solution to that?

Comment: What does the HDMI in front of notebook/PC mean? Are you sure the notebook has 2x HDMI because the specs say 1x HDMI and 1x mDP. When you say "DVI-D Single adapter works perfectly", why isn't that a solution for you? Your 1920 x 1080 dont need dual link DVI. As adapters can always cause additional issues, you may also use a direct HDMI-DVI or HDMI-DP cable without any adapter!

Comment: In your list you have HDMI 3 times mentioned for the notebook, which is confusing for 2 monitors - especially because your NEC model does not have HDMI. So the ASUS monitor on your picture is connected via mDP? There are passive and active adapters, if active (electronics integrated) then this is one difference. To get a better answer, please add the model of the "double adapter" to the question.

Comment: Still please add the model of the "double adapter" (where you mean dual link i think) and explain "dual port" - the E224wi just has one DVI port.